# Shor's algorithm in Python with qiskit - How to implement the modular exponentiation step?

Tags: qiskit, shors-algorithm, programming, modular-exponentiation

I found this code for Shor's algorithm but it always was failing at the end of the `modular_exponentiation` routine because the keyvalue of `'00000'` was not found in the dictionary on the call to `b_measure = result.get_counts()[format(i, '0{}b'.format(n+1))[-(n+1):]]`

Here is the original code in its entirety:

```
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, QuantumRegister, ClassicalRegister, Aer, execute

# Function to perform modular exponentiation
def modular_exponentiation(a, x, N):
    """Calculate a^x mod N"""
    n = N.bit_length()
    qr = QuantumRegister(n + 1)
    cr = ClassicalRegister(n + 1)
    circuit = QuantumCircuit(qr, cr)
    for i in range(n):
        circuit.initialize([1, 0], qr[i])
    circuit.initialize([1, 0], qr[n])
    for i in range(n):
        if (x >> i) & 1:
            circuit.cx(qr[n], qr[i])
    for i in range(n):
        circuit.x(qr[i])
    for i in range(2 ** n):
        b = bin(a * i % N)[2:].zfill(n)
        for j in range(n):
            if b[j] == '1':
                circuit.cx(qr[j], qr[n])
        circuit.barrier()
        for j in range(n):
            circuit.measure(qr[j], cr[j])
        circuit.measure(qr[n], cr[n])
        backend = Aer.get_backend('qasm_simulator')
        result = execute(circuit, backend, shots=1).result()
        b_measure = result.get_counts()[format(i, '0{}b'.format(n))]
        for j in range(n):
            if b_measure[j] == '1':
                circuit.x(qr[j])
    return circuit

# Function to perform Shor's algorithm
def shor(N):
    """Find the factors of N using Shor's algorithm"""
    n = N.bit_length()
    M = 2 ** n
    t = 0
    while M ** (t / 2) < 2 * n ** 2:
        t += 1
    a = 2
    for i in range(t):
        a = pow(a, M // 2, N)
        if a == 0:
            return 0
        if a == -1:
            a = N - 1
    period = None
    while period is None:
        circuit = modular_exponentiation(a, 2 ** t, N)
        backend = Aer.get_backend('qasm_simulator')
        result = execute(circuit, backend, shots=1).result()
        for key, value in result.get_counts().items():
            if value > 0:
                x = int(key, 2)
                period = x // 2 ** (n - t)
                break
    factor1 = pow(a, period // 2, N) - 1
    factor2 = pow(a, period // 2, N) + 1
    return (factor1, factor2)

# Example usage
N = 15
factors = shor(N)
print("Factors of", N, "are", factors)
```

I am doing this to learn, so I am not quantum computing expert.  I made changes to roughly the last ten lines of `modular_exponentiation` routine to eliminate the runtime errors as best as I could infer that it should work.  My changed code for the end of `modular_exponentiation` routine is as follows.  This runs, the results are consistent between runs, but the results are wrong.  For example, I tried a known prime of 419.  The program says the factors are (335, 337).  I tried increasing the number of shots to 10, but this does not seem to have any effect on the results.  Other values of `N`, such as composite numbers, also get results that are not correct.

Thanks in advance for any advice.

```
    circuit.measure(qr[n], cr[n])
        backend = Aer.get_backend('qasm_simulator')
        result = execute(circuit, backend, shots=10).result()

        #print("n = ", n)
        tempkey = format(i, '0{}b'.format(n+1))[-(n+1):]
        #print("two = ", tempkey)

        if tempkey in result.get_counts():
            b_measure = result.get_counts()[tempkey]
            for j in range(n):
                #print("b_measure, j = ", b_measure, j)
                if tempkey[j] == '1':
                #if b_measure[j] == '1':
                    circuit.x(qr[j])
        else:
            b_measure = 0
  
    return circuit
```